# UIScrollView not scrolling after changing from regular View

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a xib with a View, I changed the View class to be UIScrollView.
Now I have set contentSize to some big number (2000, 2000).

Here is my code:

This allows talking to my scrollview without casting every time:

```
- (UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return (UIScrollView *)self.view;
}
```

This I do in viewDidLoad:

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 2600);
self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

I know viewDidLoad is getting called fine. But the scrollView is not reacting. I don't have any touch responders or anything that can absorb touches.

Comment: are you using auto-layout?

Comment: @MariamN.nope, it is disabled and target is 5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a problem, I was setting superview too small.

Answer (score 2):

For this, first set delegate of scrollView inside your xib files then create an IBIoutlet for your scrollview. Remind that scrollView should connect with its refrencing outlet then Assign a propertyy as Strong to your scrollView.

```
  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
```

and synthesize it.

```
  @synthesize scrollView;
```

then try to set contentSize.

```
 scrollView.delegate=self;
 scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 2600);
 scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

I hope it works for you.

Comment: Nope, not working. I have even tried making separate scroll view and embedding my other views into it, and even that refuses to scroll.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in `viewDidLoad` and type `po self.scrollView ` what is the output?

Comment: ok make your scrollview property as strong and synthesize it. If you declared any IBOutlet for your scrollview then just use that outlet in place of self.scrollView. Or if not then alloc your scrollView before set it's contentSize

Comment: use self.scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc] init]; If you are not using any IBOutlet for your scrollview

Comment: @AaronBrager $0 = 0x1e094850 <UIScrollView: 0x1e094850; frame = (0 0; 730 579); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1e069c60>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1e094a20>; contentOffset: {0, 0}

Comment: I tried removing all gesture recognizers but that didn't help.

Comment: Does your scrollview have any subviews?

Comment: Hi Dvole , Please have a look on my updated code . Just apply this according to above given manner. Please let me know if any problem occurs.  Thanks